# Remote Access VPN traffic is not properly routing through to Site-To-Site VPN tunnel (Cisco ASA)

Tags: cisco, vpn

We have two ASA 5505s.  One accepts remote connections from clients coming into our office, the other has a tunnel from our office into AWS.

In the attached diagram, the red lines denote ping paths.  I'm able to ping from a VPN client all the way to the AWS-VPN ASA.  I'm also able to ping from an AWS instance all the way to the remote access VPN ASA.  But I can't seem to ping past these firewalls into the VPN tunnel/clients they support.

I've attached the routing tables of each ASA.

[image]

ASA-01

```
Gateway of last resort is x.58.107.57 to network 0.0.0.0

S*    0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 [1/0] via x.58.107.57, OUTSIDE
C        x.58.107.56 255.255.255.252 is directly connected, OUTSIDE
L        x.58.107.58 255.255.255.255 is directly connected, OUTSIDE
C        172.16.0.0 255.255.252.0 is directly connected, COMPUTE
L        172.16.0.1 255.255.255.255 is directly connected, COMPUTE
C        172.16.8.0 255.255.254.0 is directly connected, GUEST
L        172.16.8.1 255.255.255.255 is directly connected, GUEST
C        172.16.10.0 255.255.254.0 is directly connected, TRUSTED
L        172.16.10.1 255.255.255.255 is directly connected, TRUSTED
C        172.16.12.0 255.255.254.0 is directly connected, DMZ
L        172.16.12.1 255.255.255.255 is directly connected, DMZ
S     172.30.0.0 255.255.0.0 [1/0] via 172.16.0.2, COMPUTE
C        192.168.255.0 255.255.255.0 is directly connected, INFERNO
L        192.168.255.1 255.255.255.255 is directly connected, INFERNO
```

ASA-02

```
Gateway of last resort is x.142.10.213 to network 0.0.0.0

S*    0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 [1/0] via x.142.10.213, OUTSIDE-PHONES
C        x.142.10.212 255.255.255.252 is directly connected, OUTSIDE-PHONES
L        x.142.10.214 255.255.255.255 is directly connected, OUTSIDE-PHONES
C        172.16.0.0 255.255.252.0 is directly connected, COMPUTE
L        172.16.0.2 255.255.255.255 is directly connected, COMPUTE
S        172.16.4.0 255.255.255.0 [1/0] via 172.16.0.1, COMPUTE
C        172.16.60.0 255.255.254.0 is directly connected, PHONES
L        172.16.60.1 255.255.255.255 is directly connected, PHONES
S     172.30.0.0 255.255.0.0 [1/0] via x.142.10.213, OUTSIDE-PHONES
```

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score -1):

I had erroneously configured a local route on my testing laptop...

Whoops.